# Jest mock a constructor

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs

I am using Angular with Jest to mock a class. I am finding difficulty in mocking the constructor as the test function is invoked within the constructor. Any input on how to mock the constructor with jest would be helpful

```
export class AppComponent {


constructor(){

this.test();

}

test(){

return 'Test'
}
}
```

test

```
describe( 'AppComponent', () => {
    let fixture: WorkerFormComponent;

    beforeEach( () => {
        
        fixture = new AppComponent(
            
        );
    });
```

Comment: Please, explain your case. Mocking a constructor doesn't make sense in JS because `constructor` is a class itself. What are you're trying to do and why? Do you want to mock AppComponent in its own test? *I am finding difficulty in mocking the constructor as the test function is invoked within the constructor* - why is this a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not try to just mock the method inside the constructor, rather than the whole constructor itself?

```
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let component: WorkerFormComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<WorkerFormComponent>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(WorkerFormComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

  it('should mock and call the test function', () => {
    const testFnSpy = jest.spyOn(component, 'test')
                          .mockImplementation(() => 'Mock Value Returned');
    component.fireMethod(); // some method unrelated to the constructor
    expect(testFnSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

This solution uses a spy, if you wish to remove the `mockImplementation`, you can do so.