# Jest Mock Default Constructor

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, web3js

The test:

```
import Web3 from 'web3';

jest.mock('web3', ()=>{
    return jest.fn().mockImplementation(()=>'Hello, world!')
});

describe('app', ()=>{
    test('mock web3', ()=>{
        console.log('web3:', Web3);
        let web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
        console.log("new web3:", web3);
    });
});
```

`package.json`:

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "dependencies": {
        "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
        "web3": "^1.7.5"
    },
    "devDependencies":{
    },
    "scripts": {
        "test": "react-scripts test"
    }
}
```

Invoke with `npm i && npm test;`. The first `console.log` shows that I have mocked the module. The second `console.log` shows that something went wrong. The output of the second log statement is

> new web3: mockConstructor {}

but I expect something like

> new web3: "Hello, world!"

I've tried many permutations including moving the import below `jest.mock` and changing the import to `const Web3 = require('web3');`. If I remove the `require` or `import`, the test fails with "ReferenceError: Web3 is not defined" as expected.

I've reviewed other questions including [Jest : mock constructor function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64382021), [Jest mock a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67391987), and [Mock a dependency's constructor Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47606545), which suggest that this method should work. One salient difference is that I'm mocking a default import's constructor rather than a named import.

How do I mock the Web3 constructor to return a mocked object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, you can't use a `jest.fn` like that. It seems that you could, and lots of documentation suggests you can, so it's probably a bug. As a workaround, use a regular function:

```
jest.mock('web3', ()=>{
    return function notJestFn() {return 'Hello, world!';}
});
```

Comment: That's unacceptable! Hopefully jest will correct this problem soon.